# Matrix Formulation of Equations

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, linear-algebra

I am trying to learn statistical learning and machine learning independently. One of the main challenges I am facing is that many resources/books use matrix formulation when expressing equations. I am having trouble understanding equations when they are in the matrix formulation. My background is in chemistry and medicine, but I took an introductory linear algebra class during my undergrad years. Could you please recommend a resource to help me learn/understand matrix formulation.

I would really appreciate any advice.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though there are lots of great resources for what you are asking, I really want to recommend [Prof. Gilbert Strang's MIT 18.06](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE7DDD91010BC51F8) and [matrix methods in machine learning](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUl4u3cNGP63oMNUHXqIUcrkS2PivhN3k) to you if you are not aware of that. It's on Youtube. I watched his lectures at the beginning of my graduate study like watching movies, he is a great lecturer.

A complementary resource I would recommend is [3Blue1Brown's youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNk_zzaMoSs&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab&index=1). Following that you'll have a solid understanding of system of linear equations geometrically.

Comment: Thx for ur response. Is there a specific topic of linear algebra that is specific to my question?

Comment: I think if you understand the concepts of column space and row space, then you'll feel comfortable to write system of linear equations in matrix form. In the context of ML, a simple linear model is the linear combination of features and weight, which is multiplication of two vectors $\mathbf x^T\mathbf w$, for a fully connected neural network layer, you'll have multiplication of an input vector and a weight matrix.